# Low feature usage on desktop - should I keep it?

Tags: user-behavior, web-app, mobile-first

I have geo-lookup feature that we implemented primarily for mobile users as their use case requires it. But on desktop the feature works in a similar way but the users just type in a location.

The question is should I just switch off the geo-location button on desktop or keep it because it's built, it works, it serves a small percentage of users.

I know the mobile users want results near to them, while I believe desktop browsers are browsers further afield or in locations not local to them.

Comment: Is it causing any negatives by being there on the desktop?

Answer (score 1):

Parallelism between your platforms is a valuable thing. It helps you in your design process, makes documentation easier, helps users move from one platform to the other, and may increase your sales.

It sounds like your desktop "where am I" doesn't function automatically as it does for your mobile app. If it's easy to upgrade your desktop functionality to match your mobile then I'd keep the function with the eye towards upgrading it. For example, laptop users, who I assume fall under your "desktop" platform, would definitely find it useful.

If the desktop feature is destined to remain a semi-useless wart, then removing it may be the right thing: having a feature which looks useful but ends up being a dead-end can annoy users.